# Angular 8 - HTTP Requests gets cancelled when component destroyed - how to prevent this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a subscription in a component for an `HttpClient` call in a service, and when the call is triggered and listened to and I navigate out of the component the request gets cancelled, how do I prevent this from happening? (tried to not complete the the `this.destroy$` in the `takeUntil` when `onDestroy` is triggered, also tried to simply subscribe without any pipes)

Code:

Component:

```
private onCtrlValueChanges(event: ControlValueChangesEvent) {
    this.commonService.setRowConfig({ tbl: this.TABLE_NAME, moneln: 0 });
    this.commonService.updateFieldInTable({
      moneln: 0,
      key: event.ctrlName,
      value: event.value,
      ctrl: event.ctrl,
      tbl: this.TABLE_NAME,
    }).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.rc === 99) {
          return;
        }
    });
}
```

Service: (after some other code gets executed)

```
private executeReq(method: string, url: string, req: any) {
    return this.http[method](url, req);
}
```

This happens when I navigate out (network tab screenshot):

[image]

Comment: you can susbscribe to `http` result in your `service` itself, and then return that data from service in from `observable`

Comment: You have applied an operator method, `takeUntil(this.destroy$)`. Usually this will be used for unsubscribing from open services on component destroy. May be that will be the problem. HTTP method subscription doesn't need explicit cancellation. So avoid `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` and check.

Comment: Hi thanks, i tried deleting the takeuntill and tried subscribing without any operators at all, seems that this is not the problem. I will try shaktimaan's method and let you know if it works.

Comment: shaktimaan's method worked, thanks!